# Can i get any link or transaction id for recepient after payout execution in PayPal?

Tags: .net, paypal

I create payout request with [PayPal-NET-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK). Transaction executed normal (money sending to recepient), but in response I can`t find any idenitys for tracking transaction from user side. How I can get any info for building url, witch will prove user payout success finalizing?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you will get the transaction id from Execute response (provided no exception) parse the resonse and check for id 
under related_resource array sale/order object transaction->related_resource->sale->id/transaction->related_resource->order->id (for V1) and id under resposne object for V2
Refer the below links for version V1 sample respone - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_execute
version V2 sample Response - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_capture